# IIS 404 error from Apache php wordpress blog

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, iis

I have configured ApacheLounge on the localhost port 8282 on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.
I have also installed PHP, MySQL & Wordpress blog to a test website in Apache Server.
The Apache website works fine on port http://localhost:8282/TestWebsite/index.php.
I have created a blog folder at the root folder of the website. I have unzipped wordpress 4.2.2 in the blog folder and configured it correctly with MySQL server.

All links work properly on the website except the blog link.
When I click on the blog link it redirects from ***localhost:8282/TestWebsite/blog/*** to ***localhost/TestWebsite/blog/***

Displaying a error page from IIS
which is as below
***HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.***

**Detailed Error Information**
 1. Module  IIS Web Core
 2. Notification    MapRequestHandler
 3. Handler StaticFile
 4. Error Code  0x80070002
 5. Requested URL   http://localhost:80/testwebsite/blog/
 6. Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testwebsite\blog\
 7. Logon Method    Anonymous
 8. Logon User  Anonymous

I dont understand why would it redirect to IIS port number 80 where it is not hosted at all.

Please anyone help.

Comment: This should be a super user site question on WordPress configuration. Make sure you fill the blog address in settings with the port number or it always assumes port 80.

Comment: where do i have to make this setting change?